# issues executeScript permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I'm trying to inject some code into the selected tab context from the background script but I've some problems with the permissions.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "prova",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"console.log('Not done!');"});
    sendResponse({});
  });
```

**myscript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    console.log("Done!");
  });
```

That's the error appears in the background console:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot
>   access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request
>   permission to access the respective host.

I really appreciate every suggestion.
Thanks a ton.

Comment: See [activeTab documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) for a list of actions that activate this permission.

Answer (score 6):

From [Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) section:

> To insert code into a page, your extension must have cross-origin permissions for the page. It also must be able to use the chrome.tabs module. You can get both kinds of permission using the manifest file's permissions field.

That means you need to request a permit for the host where you want to run a code.
So, your `permissions` section in the `manifest.json` should be like:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "http://*.example.com/",
]
```

Take a look at [host match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

**EDIT 1:**

I also noticed that you using a `content-script` and `programmatic injection`. These two ways to run code in a tab makes almost the same job but with the different ways.

1. `content_script` section from the manifest helps to run a script on every page that matches a host pattern.
2. programmatic injection (PI) also helps to run a code (file or a string). But host permission for that should be set via section `permissions` in the manifest. PI uses when a script needs to run rarely, not on every page.

Comment: I modified the permissions into: "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
  ] but the error still appears. I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: I utilized the programmatic injection only for access to the page context and intercept xhr call.